# Get list of post by specific position in query

Tags: wordpress

I need create a loop with specifics post but I would like do it by position (not by id) of all of them. I want to use a single loop with specific position.

Example: (2, 5, 9, etc)

I tried to use `wp_query` methods but my php knowledge is little.

Comment: What do you mean by "position"?

Comment: "position" is the natural order os post.

Example: The first post, second post, third post, etc.

I want print posts in any order (without id)

Comment: You want random active posts inside loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside the loop, create a counter variable:

`$post_number = 1;`

Then, while you're in the loop, you can check on the contents of the variable to see which post you are at.  For instance, in the following example, only the first and second posts will be shown.

Just before you end the loop, add to the counter using `$post_number++`.

```
// Start loop

if ($post_number == 1 || $post_number == 2){
  // standard loop contents ( the_title(), the_content(), etc)
}

$post_number++;

// stop loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not try inside a loop for an example:

```
if ($idpost == "4")
{
    // print...
}
```

Comment: Good but i wish a specific posts order, not to change individual markup. I only need print any post group in any position or order